# Exclude leading characters within regex group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to extract a group with a fixed length from a string, but then ignore leading zeroes.

Example:

```
String: 1a2300245filler060403105543a
            ^^^^^      ^^^^^^
```

Current regex: `.{4}(?<part_x>[\d]{5})filler(?<part_y>[\d]{6})`

This gives me :

```
part_x = 00245

part_y = 060403

Is there some way to remove the leading zeroes from the grouping to get this?

part_x = 245

part_y = 60403
```

Note that the initial length of part_x and part_y is fixed (5 and 6 respectively). I just want to trim the leading zeroes somehow in the regex.

Comment: it seems difficult to perform this inside the regex ... you may do this afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little awkward to selectively match and capture overlapping subexpressions like this, but here's a trick you can use in this particular case and cases like it:

```
.{4}(?=\d{5}(.++))0{0,4}(?<part_x>\d+(?=\1))filler(?=\d{6}(.*+))0{0,5}(?<part_y>\d+(?=\3))
```

The trick here is `(?=\d{5}(.++))` peeks ahead of the current matching point to ensure 5 digits are present (as you mandated), but then `(.++)` goes further and captures the rest of the subject string for later testing. Then, potential leading '0's are consumed outside of the capture, leaving `(?<part_x>\d+(?=\1))` to match the rest of the digits, looking ahead once more to verify that it stops matching digits at the position where `\1`, captured earlier, follows.

part_x and part_y should then be populated as required.

If you want something that's conceptually easier to understand, you can use the following to match, for example, 5 digits and capture without leading zeroes:

```
(?|0([1-9]\d{3})|00([1-9]\d\d)|000([1-9]\d)|0000(\d))
```